# Best way to permute contents of each column in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shuffle

What's the best way to efficiently permute the contents of each column in a numpy array?

What I have is something like:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(16).reshape((4, 4))
>>> arr
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])

>> # Shuffle each column independently to obtain something like
array([[  8,  5, 10,  7],
       [ 12,  1,  6,  3],
       [  4,  9, 14, 11],
       [  0, 13,  2, 15]])
```

Comment: A recent [discussion](https://www.marshut.net/kpwyti/request-for-enhancement-to-numpy-random-shuffle.html) on the `numpy` development boards points to this functionality being added, hopefully. That also suggests that there isn't a satisfactory way of doing this with what we already have available in `numpy` 1.9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your array is multi-dimensional, [`np.random.permutation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) permutes along the first axis (columns) by default:

```
>>> np.random.permutation(arr)
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

However, this shuffles the row indices and so each column has the same (random) ordering.

The simplest way of shuffling each column independently could be to loop over the columns and use [`np.random.shuffle`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) to shuffle each one in place:

```
for i in range(arr.shape[1]):
    np.random.shuffle(arr[:,i])
```

Which gives, for instance:

```
array([[12,  1, 14, 11],
       [ 4,  9, 10,  7],
       [ 8,  5,  6, 15],
       [ 0, 13,  2,  3]])
```

This method can be useful if you have a very large array which you don't want to copy because the permutation of each column is done in place. On the other hand, even simple Python loops can be very slow and there are quicker NumPy methods such as the one provided by @jme.

Comment: how can I permute 3 columns but in the same way? not independently? `np.random.shuffle(X[:, [0,2,4]]` does not work

Comment: Using a for loop may not be the best approach when working with a package like Numpy which is designed to avoid Pythonic for loops.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another way of doing this:

```
def permute_columns(x):
    ix_i = np.random.sample(x.shape).argsort(axis=0)
    ix_j = np.tile(np.arange(x.shape[1]), (x.shape[0], 1))
    return x[ix_i, ix_j]
```

A quick test:

```
>>> x = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
>>> permute_columns(x)
array([[ 8,  9,  2,  3],
       [ 0,  5, 10, 11],
       [ 4, 13, 14,  7],
       [12,  1,  6, 15]])
```

The idea is to generate a bunch of random numbers, then `argsort` them within each column independently. This produces a random permutation of each column's indices.

Note that this has sub-optimal asymptotic time complexity, since the sort takes time `O(n m log m)` for an array of size `m x n`. But since Python's `for` loops are pretty slow, you actually get better performance for all but very tall matrices.

Answer (score 0):

To perform a permutation along the row axis of an array, you can use the following code:

```
np.random.permutation(arr) # If you want to make a copy of the array
```

Or:

```
np.random.shuffle(arr) # if you want to change the array in-place
```

However, if you have a multi-dimensional array, you can use the following code to perform the permutation along a specific axis:

```
sampler = np.random.permutation(4) # Size of the selected axis
df.take(sampler, axis=0) # You can select your desired axis from here
```

##### For example, suppose you want to permute the following array along its second axis:

###### Permutate this over axis 1

```
arr = np.arange(20).reshape((4, 5))
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])
```

###### You can define the sampler as follows:

```
sampler = np.random.permutation(5)
array([2, 1, 3, 4, 0])
```

###### Then, you can apply the permutation using the take() method:

```
arr.take(sampler, axis = 1)

Out:
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  0,  4],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  5,  9],
       [11, 12, 13, 10, 14],
       [16, 17, 18, 15, 19]])
```

---

##### If you want to shuffle all the elements along all axises you can do this

```
np.random.permutation(arr.flatten()).reshape((4, 5)) # This makes a copy of the array
```